# Why DFSInotifyEventInputStream has been removed in Hadoop 3.1.0?

Tags: maven, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using DFSInotifyEventInputStream to watch for events in HDFS.

I have maven project where I import `hadoop-hdfs` and `hadoop-common`.

If I use version 2.7.1 on both dependencies, the `DFSInotifyEventInputStream` is correctly found. However, in the latest version of hadoop (3.1.0), this class is missing.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at:

[HDFS-8053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-8053) - Move DFSIn/OutputStream and related classes to hadoop-hdfs-client

you should import `hadoop-hdfs-client`.  The JIRA also states this change went in effective version 2.8.0 and 3.0.0-alpha which is why it's also in 3.1.0.